# Microprocessors for multiple (~40) SPI devices?

Tags: spi, arm, microprocessor, atmel

I'm looking at building a product that combines over 40 LCD pushbutton switches (example [here](http://www.nkkswitches.com/pdf/IS15EBFP4RGB09YN_Wide64x32ShrtTrvl.pdf) that communicate via SPI). I've been looking at microprocessors to handle this, but I am running into trouble finding any. The highest that Atmel offers is 12 devices ([as found here](http://www.atmel.com/selector.html#(actives:!(81041,8238,8394,8362,8282,8431,8300,8358,8392,8378,8445,8236,8449,8474,8248,8264,8447,8256,8254,8286,8462,8429,8458,8466,8400,8302,8278),data:(area:'',category:'34864',pm:!((i:81041,v:!(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79)),(i:8238,v:!(0,19)),(i:8394,v:!(0,26)),(i:8362,v:!(2,47)),(i:8282,v:!(0,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)),(i:8431,v:!(1,40)),(i:8300,v:!(1,9)),(i:8358,v:!(2,75)),(i:8392,v:!(0,1)),(i:8378,v:0),(i:8445,v:!(1,4,5,6,7,9)),(i:8236,v:!(0,35)),(i:8449,v:!(1,11)),(i:8474,v:!(0)),(i:8248,v:!(0,1)),(i:8264,v:!(0,5)),(i:8447,v:!(0,1)),(i:8256,v:!(1,2,3,4)),(i:8254,v:!(3,18)),(i:8286,v:!(0,3)),(i:8462,v:!(0,10)),(i:8429,v:!(10,10)),(i:8458,v:!(0,8)),(i:8466,v:!(1,2,3,4,5)),(i:8400,v:!(0,20)),(i:8302,v:!(0,1,2)),(i:8278,v:!(0,1,2))),view:list),sc:1))), and ARM isn't looking better.

What is the best way to go about controlling this many SPI devices? Do I need to link several processors together into a master?

Comment: You do realize that you are not forced to use a dedicated slave select pin?  You can actually use *any* GPIO or scheme you like of generating them, as long as you make sure they are valid in time.  So really your limit is the electrical loads on the bus.  There are ways you could deal with that, but you might consider a fan-in of slave micros batching data for a master.  Or potentially an FPGA, operating multiple busses at the same time and dealing in batch data with the host MCU.

Comment: You realize that the XMEGA devices your link refers to can handle up to 12 SPI busses as Master, not only 12 SPI clients? You could split the 40 devices over 10 busses for example and should still have enough GPIOs free for slave select lines. But maybe I am missing the point.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I did not realize that, thanks.  I'm a programmer who is trying to get into embedded, so there is plenty of learning to be done.

Comment: @Rev1.0 Probably not missing the point, i'm just new to this.  So does the "split 40 devices over 10 busses" offer a solution to the Input Capacitance issue that Majenko brought up below?

Comment: Can you provide a datasheet that shows typical connections and the SPI protocol that the LCD switch uses?

Comment: @kfriede: You provided no information about expected bus trace length and SPI clock speed requirements, so if you need no keep the number of clients per bus low is hard to tell. Depending on the physical button layout, maybe split the 40 devices into 4 buses and locate the controller in the "center" to keep traces as short as possible. If you have about 10 clients per bus and can keep the trace lengths below 10cm you should be able to get some 1MHz+ clock speed running. But thats just a quick personal estimation.

Comment: @user2943160 the link titled "here" above has it, which directs to: http://www.nkkswitches.com/pdf/IS15EBFP4RGB09YN_Wide64x32ShrtTrvl.pdf

Comment: @kfriede That datasheet provides *neither* the SPI protocol *nor* a typical connection diagram. Which is why I asked. Daisy-chaining the devices could be very useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either use demultiplexers such as the 74HC138 for the slave select, or use diode-ORs with a matrix select.

Or if the protocol allows for it, you could chain all the buttons together and use one long SPI transfer for all of them.

Comment: Now that you say that, the demultiplexer makes total sense.  Didn't even cross my mind.  Thank you.

Comment: As Majenko's answer points out, you'll also want to multiplex the MISO (master in slave out) pins, and demux the MOSI (master out slave in) pins.

Comment: No, you demultiplex slave select and bus the MISO and MOSI lines. The whole point of SS is that you can tie all of the MOSI together and, with the correct slave devices, tie all of the MISO lines together.

Answer (score 4):

One word of caution when you are using that many SPI devices on a single bus:

- Input Capacitance.

That number of devices will put a massive amount of capacitance on the bus. Unless you take precautions it will severely limit your maximum bus frequency, and thus the speed at which you can update display contents etc.  (Basically the input capacitance coupled with the output impedance of the MCU's IO pins form a low-pass filter turning higher frequency square waves into more like sine waves, which SPI doesn't like - it messes with the timing).

If you are happy to use lower communication speeds then that's fine - however I would recommend splitting the bus into a number of smaller segments and buffering each SCK and MOSI signal to keep the capacitance on each segment to within reasonable levels. An alternative is to use a single high current drive buffer to reduce the output impedance of the SCK and MOSI pins.

Comment: Quite good hint. I'd strongly prefer splitting busses over buffering. This will keep peak currents much lower (only one bus at the time needs to be switching) reducing  noise and decoupling issues.

Answer (score 1):

There is **NO limit** to the number of SPI devices that can be hooked together to a single SPI, assuming that there are enough IOs for selecting the right device.

But practically there might be some difficulties when the number is more at higher speeds. But that is rare.

You can connect MISO MOSI and SCK parallely to all devices. But you should connect GPIO of controller to SS(slave select) pin in one to one manner.

Go for GPIO expander or multiplexers only if the number of GPIOs on controller is limited